# Travelling Salesman: Using Matrix Routing API (HERE Maps)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, maps, here-api

My company recently purchased an Enterprise Licence for the HERE Platform. In the application I'm working on, I need to solve the Travelling Salesman Problem, which means that given a starting point, a destination point and several "waypoints" between them, it has to calculate me the most optimal route to go from `A-n-B`.

For example, if I have these three addresses in the following order

```
1. London
2. Moscow
3. Paris
```

Without optimizing it I would get a route that goes from London to Moscow, and from there back to Paris. The optimal route for these addresses would be

```
1. London
2. Paris
3. Moscow
```

A real world example would be

```
- Start: Budapest
- End: Paris
- Waypoint 1: Berlin
- Waypoint 2: Vienna
- Waypoint 3: Stockholm
- Waypoint 4: Madrid
- Waypoint 5: Rome
- Waypoint 6: Bucharest
- Waypoint 7: Frankfurt
- Waypoint 8: Munchen
- Waypoint 9: Caen
- Waypoint 10: Barcelona
```

So the application takes in the addresses and outputs the shortest A.K.A the "optimal" route to go from Budapest to Paris.

I've spoken with HERE's support, and they told me that I need to use the Matrix Routing API for this (developers guide PDF [here](http://developer.here.com/documentation/download/routing_matrix_lbsp/6.2.32/Matrix%20Routing%20API%20v6.2.32%20Developer's%20Guide.pdf)), however I don't really understand how can it solve my problem.

In the documentation as far as I can see you can define multiple starting points and multiple destinations, so it would compute the distances between these, but I don't see any way to have one fixed starting position and another fixed destination with multiple waypoints in between them. Is what we need possible with the Matrix Routing API? If yes, could someone show me some pseudo code how to use it?

Comment: Actually the definition of the travelling salesman problem is (from the wikipedia): "Given a list of cities and the distances between each pair of cities, what is the shortest possible route that visits each city exactly once and returns to the origin city?" Even though you are stating that you need to solve the travelling salesman problem, the example that you have given is not the travelling salesman problem. If it's just a matter of computing the shortest path from Budapest to Paris via any number of waypoints, this is known as the shortest path problem, and much easier to solve.

Comment: @OP do you want to find the shortest route from source to destination or the shortest route while visiting all the cities in between?

Comment: @user1990169 Yes, exactly.

Comment: @wookie919 Do you have any ready-to-be-used solutions for this? I'll search around the web, thanks for your insight!

Comment: @TrisztánThar I am confused, because user1990169 asked "do you want to find A OR B", to which you answered "Yes, exactly". So which is it? Do you want to find the shortest route from the source to destination OR the shortest routes while visiting all the cities in between? The first problem can be easily solved using Dijkstra's algorithm. There is no easy method of solving the second problem that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

P 6 of the PDF you point to says

"The output of the API is often used as an input to other
optimization methods, such as:
• computing the shortest round trip for a set of locations"

I deduce from this that you cannot solve the TSP using their API alone, because then nothing would be left for "other optimization methods" to do. I suspect that they intend you to use their API to work out the point to point distances between nodes, and then feed this to a TSP algorithm to do the hard bit.

I was somewhat bemused to see a requirement one day that we should build a system that solved the TSP. It turned out that there is GIS software that will do this well enough to be practically useful, and we complied with the requirement by installing the software the customer had in fact been using for this in other systems. See e.g. from http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Algorithms_used_by_Network_Analyst "The TSP is a combinatorial problem, meaning there is no straightforward way to find the best sequence. Heuristics are used to find good solutions to these types of problems in a short amount of time. ... the exact implementation of the tabu search is proprietary, but it has been researched and developed extensively in-house at ESRI to quickly yield good results."

PS - despite what ESRI says there are tractable combinatorial problems, although the TSP is not, as far as we know, one of thme.

Answer (score -1):

the problem of finding the path that optimizes the time or distance to visit different places is a very difficult problem because it is necessary to analyze N factorial solutions (where N is the number of places to visit)For example if N = 7 there are 5040 solutions, if N = 8 are 40320, if N = 9 are 362880 and so on.

It's a difficult problem in computer science because it cannot be solved in polynomial time. It's an NP-hard (Non-deterministic Polynomial-time hard), you can find a sub-optimal solution using heuristic and approximation algorithms. I used one of these algorithms to solve the problem for iPhone/iPad http://igioel.com/app/OptimalRoute/